# Is there a general value for a failed execution?

Tags: c, return-value

I was wondering whether there are any pre-agreed values, coming from the old days of C language, that reflect tha function execution threw exception/terminated abruptly/failed for  any reason? Is this value 0, or -1 or is it completely up to you and no standards exist?

Comment: For some questions like `find the index of a character in a string` 0 is a legal value so `-1` indicates failures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions that return pointers usually return `NULL` to indicate failure (e.g. `malloc`).

Most POSIX functions return `0` on success, and non-zero on failure.  If they need to return a non-zero value as part of normal operation, they often return a negative value on failure.

But this is all just convention.

Answer (score 0):

One common convention is to return an invalid value, whatever it is. For instance, functions returning lengths may return -1 on failure.

General purpose error codes tend to be 0 or `NULL` to mimick malloc's behavior. POSIX, on the other hand, uses the inverse convention.

Be sure to get accustomed to `errno` for more "advanced" error checking. Many standard library routines put an error code there to be checked on failure.